# И опять, как всё-таки запустить приложение вне QT?

Tags: qtcreator

Добрый день.

Установил QT 5.7, создаю приложение QtQuick-2 с использованием компилятора MinGW53-32, компилирую приложение Release. Из QtCreator всё работает. Взял готовый скомпилированный EXEшник, скопировал DLL-ки, которые он требовал от той версии компилятора, которая использовалась при написании приложения.

Проблема - запускаю приложение - в памяти висит, но никаких окон вообще не появляется. Ни окно приложения, ни окон ошибок, вообще дупель пусто. Закрыть приложение возможно только через диспетчер задач.

Перепроверил версию компилятора - всё совпадает. Пробовал ради эксперимента копировать DLL-ки от другой версии компилятора, тогда появляется стандартная ошибка "не найдена точка входа в DLL". А с правильными DLL-ками ни ошибок, ни окна приложения...

Пробовал как с рабочим проектом, так и с пустым приложением "Hello World", результат одинаковый - из QtCreator всё работает, а вне его - дупель пусто.

Что я делаю не так ? Как решить проблему ?

P.s. использую Windows 10 x64 корпоративная.

P.p.s. Попытался запустить скомпилированное приложение на виртуалке под Windows XP x86, результат такой же - пусто. В памяти приложение висит, его окна нету, ошибок тоже нету.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: Попробовал я и windeployqt, тоже не помогло. Эта утилита копирует несколько большее количество разных DLL, но одна из них отличается от той, которая лежит в папке с отладчиком - Qt5Core.dll. Отличие в прописанном внутри DLL пути к папке с отладчиком - в оригинале этот путь есть ("C:/QT/...."), а после windeployqt этого пути нету.

Comment: В результате программа перестаёт запускаться даже на моём компьютере, где установлен QtCreator. Если после работы windeployqt я меняю DLL-ку Qt5Core.dll на оригинальную, тогда программа работает. Т.е. не смотря на наличие всего необходимого комплекта DLL, который определяет Dll Collector или windeployqt, программа всё-равно не работает, если Qt5Core.dll не видит каталог с установленным MinGW отладчиком. Не смотря на то что я использовал опцию --release. Вопрос остаётся открытым.

Comment: Вопрос ещё актуален? Симптомы похожи на то, что программа не смогла загрузить qml-код. В этом случае программа должна вывести сообщение об ошибке в стандартный вывод. Посмотрите, что в нём содержится, запустив программу из командной строки. Например, там может быть сообщение "Unable to load QML module ModuleName...".

Answer (score 1):

Вместе с dll создай в папке с приложением папку platforms и кинь туда qwindows.dll из Qt/mingw/plugins/platforms. Либо скачай DLLCollector.

Comment: Это я тоже сделал - оба файла скопировал в папку /plugins/platforms/, но это не помогло. DLL Collector не пробовал, попробую, отпишусь сюда.

Comment: DLL Collector частично решил проблему - он кроме тех DLL-ок скопировал ещё 6 штук: Qt5Quick.dll, Qt5QuickTemplates2.dll, Qt5QuickControls2.dll, Qt5Widgets.dll и Qt5Svg.dll. Теперь на своём компьютере вне Qt Creater приложение запускается, но на другом (на виртуалке под XP) выдаёт ошибку, что не может найти или загрузить platform plugin "windows", хотя в папке /plugins/platforms/ лежат оба файла - qwindows.dll и qminimal.dll. Пробовал для эксперимента папку plugins/platforms/ скопировать в папки C:\Windows и C:\Windows\System32, всё-равно под XP не запускается.

Comment: У меня такое было, но закидывание папки platforms помогло. Стоп, а ты так и кидаешь, plugins/platforms? Там должна быть только папка platforms, а в ней qwindows.dll.

Comment: Я сначала в папке с приложением создал папку /plugins/platforms/, и в неё кинул оба файла. Затем попробовал папку platforms перенести в папку с приложением, т.е. без plugins, всё равно не запускается. Причём проверил уже не только под XP, но и под 7-кой.

Comment: Странно. Вот хороший фреймворк, удобно писать, но постоянно присутствует ощущение недоработанности. Либо так и было задуманно, просто я чего-то непонимаю.

Comment: Вообщем, с плагином qwindows.dll я промахнулся немного - его тоже нужно было кинуть не из папки c:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\plugins\platforms\, а из папки компилятора c:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\plugins\platforms\. На компьютере, где установлен QtCreator, вне его как запускалась программа, так и запускается. На другом компьютере окошко ошибки "не удалось найти или загрузить плагин..." уже не выскакивает. Но окна программы всё-равно нету.

Comment: P.s. Поменял путь к плагинам в DllCollector-е, он теперь стал видеть плагины, и кроме папки /platforms/ скопировал так же папку /imageformats/ ещё с 10-ю DLL-ками. Но это всё-равно не помогло.

Comment: Удалось всё-таки запустить приложение на другом компьютере (на виртуалке). Во-первых, Qt5Core.dll должен быть не оригинальным, а с удалённым из него пути к папке с установленным отладчиком ("C:/Qt/5.7/MinGW53_32"). Во-вторых, кроме самих DLL-ок, так же необходимо было скопировать папку QML, но не всю, в моём случае часть /QML/QtQuick/ и полностью /QML/QtQuick.2/, в общей сумме файлов на 16Мб. И только после этого программа стала запускаться на другом компьютере.

Comment: Если файл Qt5Core.dll будет оригинальным, т.е. с прописанным внутри путём к установленному отладчику, тогда данную папку QML на целевом компьютере приходится копировать в указанный в DLL-ке путь - C:\Qt\5.7\MinGW53_32\, и тогда программа тоже работает. Не знаю, стоит ли данное решение считать за ответ и за закрытую тему. Как по мне, то оно сильно кривое, хотя и решает вопрос переноса. В итоге папка с программой и со всеми необходимыми файлами весит 47 Мб, где EXE-шник самой программы - 190 Кб. Если в программу добавить мультимедию и 3D-графику, то файлов придётся копировать ещё больше.

Comment: На тот же самый HelloWorld 47 Мб... это как-то дико.

Answer (score -1):

Для этого в QT есть статическая линковка.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]